# proving the limit of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}{\rm Re}(z)={\rm Re}(z_0)\ .$$

Approach: Let $z=x+yi$ and $z_0=x_0+y_0i$
$$|x-x_0|=|(z-y_i)-(z_0-y_0i)|=|z-z_0-y_i+y_0i|$$

So basically I am trying to find a way to isolate the $|z-z_0|$. How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $|x-x_0|=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2}\leq \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}=|z-z_0|$.

Comment: Ok, so how would you set this. $|x-x_0|< \epsilon$ ...

Comment: Take $\delta=\varepsilon$ in this case. The above shows that if $|z-z_0|<\varepsilon$, then $|x-x_0|<\varepsilon$ as well.

Comment: I still have my doubts. if $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ and $|x-x_0| \leq |z-z_0|$, it doesnt mean that $|z-z_0| < \epsilon|$. Can you go over that?

Comment: You have it backwards: to show that $\lim_{z\to z_0}\Re(z)=\Re(z_0)$, you have to show that given any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|z-z_0|<\delta$, then $|x-x_0|<\varepsilon$. So take $\delta=\varepsilon$ in this case.

Comment: Oh we have to go backwards, so in this case we know that $|z-z_0|< \delta$ and if we set $\delta-\epsilon$ then the expression still hols because $|x-x_0|< \epsilon$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: For a similar problem $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \overline{z}=\overline{z_0}$. Does it make sense to say $(x-yi)-(x_0-y_0i) \leq (x+y_i)-(x_0+y_0i)$?

Comment: Even easier: $|x-iy-(x_0-iy_0)|=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}=|z-z_0|$.

Comment: And for the following one, we just have to use mod properties $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}=0$ $|\frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}|=\frac{|\overline{z}||\overline{z}|}{|z|}=|z|$ Right?

Comment: It would be best to make these separate questions.